# Creating an array of "PrintWriter" in processing?

Tags: processing

I want to create an array of the element "PrintWriter" (s) type but it tells me there is an error ! i'm new to java i don't understand why ? i think the way to declare an array is :
 `type variable name[] = new type[size]`
this is the code:

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter[10];
```

can some one help ?

Comment: yes,it did .. it is so easy i just didn't watch well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `[]` to the type on the left:

```
PrintWriter[] output = new PrintWriter[10];
```

Short explanation:

You were trying to declare a variable of type `PrintWriter` (not array) and then assign a value of type `PrintWriter[]` (an array).

Comment: well actually i don't know how i didn't notice that ... i'm so stupid . . .

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the references section of Processing 
Look for Reference under the Help menu
line 1 of the example below creates an integer array called numbers with 3 elements

```
int[] numbers = new int[3]; 
numbers[0] = 90; 
numbers[1] = 150; 
numbers[2] = 30; 
int a = numbers[0] + numbers[1]; // Sets variable 'a' to 240 
int b = numbers[1] + numbers[2]; // Sets variable 'b' to 180
```